# Diferença de velocidade entre Plink e OpenSSH

Tags: windows, ssh, mercurial

Tenho um setup com alguns repositórios Mercurial. Por questões de segurança e padronização recentemente o acesso https aos repositórios Mercurial foram desabilitados, o que obrigou todos os desenvolvedores a usarem ssh.

No Linux tudo funcionou muito bem, porém no Windows os programadores começaram a reclamar de lentidão. Usando a máquina de um colega para *troubleshooting* (Windows 7 + Mercurial 3.8.4) percebi que de fato mesmo clonar repositórios relativamente pequenos leva um bom tempo:

```
$ time hg clone ssh://hg@meurepo.com/meuprojeto
destination directory: meuprojeto
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 52 changesets with 216 changes to 55 files
updating to branch default
33 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

real    2m58.229s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Seguindo algumas dicas ([como esssa](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-mercurial-728138122.html#SetupSSHforMercurial-step3Step4.EnableSSHcompressionforMercurial)), tentei habilitar compressão no `TortoisePlink`. Também tentei usar uma versão beta do `Plink` (teoricamente mais rápida) com pouca ou nenhuma diferença.

Instalei então o `Cygwin` com `OpenSSH` e a diferença foi brutal:

```
$ time hg clone ssh://hg@meurepo.com/meuprojeto
destination directory: meuprojeto
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 52 changesets with 216 changes to 55 files
updating to branch default
33 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

real    0m15.794s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

O clone foi ~11 vezes mais rápido! Ainda assim 3 vezes mais lento do que no Linux, mas 15 segundos é um tempo aceitável.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem ideia do que faz o `OpenSSH` tão mais rápido do que o `Plink` quando usamos Mercurial no Windows? Existe alguma coisa que possa ser feita para melhorar a performance do `Plink`?

Acredito que `OpenSSH` seja uma solução aceitável uma vez que o público alvo são desenvolvedores. Dito isso o pessoal do Windows não está muito acostumado com o mundo Linux e a integração do `TortoiseHG + Plink + Pageant` acaba sendo bem menos alienígena do que `Cygwin + OpenSSH + ssh-agent`. Existe alguma outra opção bom boa performance e usabilidade para o Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltando para responder minha própria pergunta um ano e meio depois.

Muita coisa mudou nesse meio tempo, inclusive, o Windows 10 está ganhando uma versão nativa de OpenSSH. Nada mais do que o [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki) mencionado [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141972/100) do [Marcos Zolnowski](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64/marcos-zolnowski) que agora pode ser instalado como uma [funcionalidade opcional do Windows](https://pplware.sapo.pt/microsoft/windows/instalar-usar-cliente-ssh-windows-10/).

O WSL também funciona bem, apesar de não ser substituto para um cliente nativo (a integração com programas externos ao WSL ainda deixa a desejar).

A *performance* do Mercurial no Windows ainda não está em pé de igualdade com o Linux. No Linux em média clonar via SSH costuma ser bem mais rápido do que via HTTPS. Dito isso todos os clientes SSH que testei estão conseguindo clonar repositórios de tamanho médio (50 - 100 MB) em questão de segundos e não minutos. Sinceramente eu não tenho mais utilizado o Cygwin para muita coisa (e isso é ótimo).

Seguem alguns tempos com os clientes SSH mais populares na minha máquina pessoal (*Mercurial Distributed SCM 4.4.1 + Windows 10*):

#### HTTPS

```
hg clone https://aaccioly@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg --time
time: real 23.926 secs (user 13.125+0.000 sys 2.891+0.000)
```

#### Win32-OpenSSH 0.0.24.0 (OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.5.3)

> ssh = "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe" -C -a -x

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg --time
time: real 22.402 secs (user 13.203+0.000 sys 2.859+0.000)
```

#### WSL openSUSE Leap 42.3 (OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n-fips  7 Dec 2017)

> ssh = ssh -C -a -x

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg --time
time: real 23.990 secs (user 11.940+0.620 sys 4.620+0.760)
```

#### Git For Windows  2.15.1.2 (OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017)

> ssh = "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" -C -a -x

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg --time
time: real 28.191 secs (user 13.703+0.000 sys 2.734+0.000)
```

#### PuTTY (Release 0.70)

> ssh = "C:\opt\PuTTY\PLINK.exe" -ssh -2 -C -a -x

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg --time
time: real 28.630 secs (user 14.281+0.000 sys 2.641+0.000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Futuramente: [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)

Atualmente, não parece existir muitas opções interessantes.

É um tiro no escuro, mas poderia tentar usar o [Win32 OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH).

Comment: Pois é Marcos. Suporte oficial da Microsoft vai ser lindo. Eu dei uma brincada com o OpenSSH no PowerShell em casa ontem e toda a parte de `ssh-agent` funcionou direitinho. Para  o `TortoiseHg` tudo ficou transparente (o `ssh-agent` registrado como serviço levanta as chaves). Em termos de performance, no momento o Cygwin é um pouco mais rápido (mas isso não deve ser verdade por muito tempo)... Vou ver se consigo colocar isso para rodar no Windows 7 (meu colega não conseguiu).

Comment: Estava pensando numa idéia maluca aqui. Já tentou instalar o Linux no VirtualBox, e rodar o TortoiseHg por lá? Será que a performance seria melhor?

Comment: Olá Marcos, por curiosidade eu fiz o teste. Operações como `clone` tem *performance* muito próxima do ambiente original Linux (são mais rápidas que no Cygwin). Dito isso, o trabalho de colocar uma VM para rodar, configurar pastas compartilhadas, etc faz do `Cygwin` uma opção mais viável. Não surgindo nenhuma outra alternativa nativa (até agora não encontrei nada) acho que a melhor opção será inicializar o `ssh-agent` como serviço e adicionar as chave no *startup*. Encontrei até [um script](https://github.com/ericblade/ssh-agent-cmd) para isso.

Comment: Entendo, não é nada prático. Mas se você começar a usar repositórios intermediários, como RepoDraft -> RepoPublic -> RepoCanonico, pode vir a ser interessante. O RepoDraft, seria no Windows na fase Draft, o público seria no seu VirtualBox/Linux, e o canônico é o servidor externo. Com o Windows se comunicando via HTTP com o Linux, sendo numa rede virtual interna, seria seguro. O Linux continuaria se conectando com o servidor externo utilizando o SSH. Para completar, o Linux poderia estar no pendrive, e o VirtualBox poderia iniciar diretamente de lá, facilitando a mobilidade entre computadores.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um artigo que fala sobre a lentidão do git no Windows:
https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow

Uma forma de resolver é com `git lfs clone...`, [veja aqui](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/git-lfs-12-clone-faster/).

Boa parte dos comandos executados no Windows são lentos, como git, ruby, python, etc... Tecnicamente não sei explicar o motivo, mas esta relacionado a Arquitetura e Kernel do SO. O Cygwin emula um Linux.

Comment: Oi Vitor, pois é, eu vi que o pessoal do Git no Windows também sofre tanto com a diferença no sistema de arquivos quanto com versões [defasadas  / lentas de clientes ssh](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/107). Infelizmente por se tratar de mercurial em repositórios razoavelmente pequenos estou refém da velocidade do cliente ssh (que esse é o gargalo já ficou claro para mim). Será que existe algum tipo de configuração que possa ser feira para aumentar a performance?

Comment: Não sei se seu repositório aceita, mas voce poderia tentar clonar o repositório e trabalhar via http. O Github por exemplo permite clonar pelo http.